# How to change ListStyle in List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI `List` Appears to have a property called `ListStyle`.

How can i change the style of the list

```
struct ListView : View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
    List(Item.create().identified(by: \.id)){ row in
        NavigationButton(destination: DetailsView(item: row)) {
            RowView(item: row)
        }
    }
    .listStyle(StaticMember<PlainListStyle.Member>.self) // error here
    .foregroundColor(.red)
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("List View"))
    .statusBar(hidden: false)
    }
  }
}
```

The conforming parties of `ListStyle` protocol are

1. CarouselListStyle
2. DefaultListStyle
3. GroupedListStyle
4. PlainListStyle
5. SidebarListStyle

However i am struggling trying to set a new style for the list 
using it like this

```
.listStyle(StaticMember<PlainListStyle.Member>.self)
```

I have tried so many ways, but each style confirming to the `ListStyle` is struct, like they're not enumerated values

Anyone have an idea how to change the style of `List` ?

**Error in Xcode**

> Cannot convert value of type 'StaticMember.Type' (aka 'StaticMember>.Type') to expected argument type 'StaticMember<_>'

Using : `.listStyle(StaticMember<PlainListStyle.Member>)`

**Error in Xcode**

> Cannot convert value of type '(StaticMember).Type' (aka 'StaticMember>.Type') to expected argument type 'StaticMember<_>'

Using : `.listStyle(StaticMember<PlainListStyle()>)` or `.listStyle(StaticMember<PlainListStyle.self>)`

**Error in Xcode**

> '>' is not a postfix unary operator

Comment: i tried it still same issue

Comment: @user28434 check update on what i've used

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As of Xcode 11 beta 5, Apple requires the following, as *briefly* outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/liststyle):

```
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

The following is a breakdown on the various styles and where they can be used between **iOS** and **watchOS**, along with when they were introduced.

## iOS and watchOS

Introduced with iOS 13 and watchOS 6:

- `PlainListStyle`
- `ListStyle`
- `DefaultListStyle`

## iOS Only

Introduced with iOS 13:

- `GroupedListStyle`

Introduced with iOS 14:

- `InsetGroupedListStyle`
- `InsetListStyle`
- `SidebarListStyle`

Some answers to this question also include styles that are watchOS specific, but are not clearly marked as such, despite the question being tagged iOS. For completeness...

## watchOS Only

Introduced with watchOS 6:

- `CarouselListStyle`

Introduced with watchOS 7:

- `EllipticalListStyle`

Answer (score 13):

### Update for Xcode 13

So Apple added an extension to have a syntax similar to Xcode 11 Beta 5 and lower:

```swift
extension ListStyle where Self == GroupedListStyle {

    /// The list style that describes the behavior and appearance of a grouped
    /// list.
    ///
    /// On iOS, the grouped list style displays a larger header and footer than
    /// the ``ListStyle/plain`` style, which visually distances the members of
    /// different sections.
    public static var grouped: GroupedListStyle { get }
}
```

So again we can use this now:

```swift
.listStyle(.grouped)
```

### Update for Xcode 11 Beta 5 till Xcode 12

After Xcode Beta 5 the `listStyle(.grouped)` approach is deprecated (until Xcode 12); now Apple created a struct implementation for every style. So you should do like:
`.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())`. Same approach is applied to other styles available.

### Old implementation for pre beta 5

Just do `.listStyle(.grouped)`. For other list style use

- `.carousel`
- `.default`
- `.plain`
- `.sidebar`

Basically you are just passing `ListStyle.grouped` to the method, but thanks to swift type inference you don't need to specify the struct.
Every static member work in this way.

`StaticMember` means that there is a static member in the `ListStyle` protocol. The declaration is this.

```
extension StaticMember where Base : ListStyle {

    /// A `ListStyle` that implements the system default grouped `List`
    /// interaction and appearance.
    public static var grouped: GroupedListStyle.Member { get }
}
```

Comment: `.plain` for `PlainListStyle`

Answer (score 4):

in Xcode 11.2.1, Right answer is in the below.

```
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())

Conforming Types  ->
CarouselListStyle
DefaultListStyle
GroupedListStyle
PlainListStyle
SidebarListStyle
```

ref:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/liststyle