# How to disable SwiftUI's default behavior?

Tags: ios, swiftui

SwiftUI makes it very easy to build declarative UIs. However, sometimes they assume defaults that are not necessarily what we want.

#### Example:

When adding two buttons inside a list row, SwiftUI automatically makes the whole row touchable, and both button's actions are called on row tap. This is the default behavior, as demonstrated in their WWDC videos.

But I do not want this behavior. I want both buttons to work properly, and the row to not be tappable.

#### Question:

How can we tell our Guacamole expert (to use the WWDC reference) to stop assuming how I want my list (or any other behavior) to work?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the `List`'s  default behavior is not required, you could use a `VStack`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("foo")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
            }
            Button(action: {
                print("bar")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However if `List` is really required, then it could be customized by writing a custom [ListStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/liststyle).

(Also take a look at this question: [How to change ListStyle in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474019/how-to-change-liststyle-in-list).)

It seems that `SomethingStyle protocol` is the way Apple wants developers to use to modify native SwiftUI elements/behavior. Another example would be [ButtonStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyle) or [TextFieldStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfieldstyle), etc.

Comment: In this particular example, yes, I do need the list's default behavior for some of the rows. But for other rows I need the default behavior to be inactive (so the two buttons can work properly). 

That said, the question is a little more generic in the sense that I'd like to know how to stop default behaviours anywhere in SwiftUI.

Comment: I see. In that case you could use `ListStyle` / `ButtonStyle`, etc. I updated my answer accordingly, please take a look.

Comment: Great! I will give it a try and get back to you. Thanks, @backslash-f!

Comment: It's possible to create your own types that conform to `ButtonStyle`. It is not possible to create your own types that conform to `ListStyle`. You have to use one of the `ListStyle`-conforming types provided by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I am under the impression that Apple wants to enforce their style guidelines. Also to add onto @backslash-f answer you could also just use a for each instead of a list, this will give you a similar effect and allow much more customization.

```
struct doubleList: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(1 ..< 10) {index in
               Button(action: {
                   print("foo")
               }) {
                   Image(systemName: "photo")
                   }
               }
           }
       }
}
```

Another option to try would be to wrap an `UITableView` into an `UIViewRepresentable` and try to enable buttons that way

It seems there might be another way around this by using tap gestures

```
Image(systemName: "photo")
.gesture(TapGesture().onEnded() {
                print("action2")
                })
```

Comment: I'm under that impression as well, mainly as a way to help faster development. But they also say it's easy to create custom functionality, which is not quite the case for everything. I was trying to avoid bringing UIKit to the solution, but I guess that's one way of doing it. Thanks for the input, @yawnobleix.

Comment: @R.Farias Instead of using a button try it with a gesture, I added more details